# Limit of the sum of a factorial series

Tags: limits, factorial

Is there any function $f$ over the positive integers such that

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n} {\frac{n!}{(n-i)!}}}{f(n)} = 1$$

and

$$f(n)\not\equiv\sum_{i=0}^{n} {\frac{n!}{(n-i)!}}$$
What is the definition of the function if it exists, or if it doesn't exist, why not?

(updated)

Comment: Do you want $f(n)$ to depend on $i$ also? As it stands the question does  not make sense. Besides if $f(n)=\frac {n!} {(n-i)!}$ then  you get the limit as $ \infty$, not $1$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy f(n) should not depend on i.

Comment: Understood now, thanks both. I meant to divide the whole result of the summation by f(n). Fixing.

Comment: I have edited my answer to accommodate your second condition in the revised form.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As it stands the question has an obvious answer: take $f(n) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \frac {n!} {(n-i)!}+1$.

PS If $a_n \to \infty$ there are lots of sequences $f(n)$ such that $\frac {a_n} {f(n)} \to 1$; for example $f(n)=a_n+c\sqrt {a_n}$ (where $c$ is a constant) is one such.

Comment: Dear downvoters, OP only asked about existence of $f(n)$ and the did nor seek any simple expression for it.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{split}
\sum_{i=0}^{n} {\frac{n!}{(n-i)!}} &= n! \sum_{i=0}^{n} {\frac {1}{(n-i)!}}\\
&= n! \sum_{i=0}^{n} {\frac {1}{i!}}\\
&= n!(e +o(1))
\end{split}$$
Therefore you can take $f(n)= e.n!$

Answer (score 0):

For any function $g(n)$ that diverges to infinity,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{g(n)+o(g(n))}{g(n)}=1.$$